# Help re.search python length

Tags: python, regex

Is it possible to read the length of re.search's output?

For example:

```
import re

list=['lost','post','cross','help','cost']

for i in range(len(list)):
  output = re.search('os', list[i])
```

Can I read output length?

Comment: Do ***not*** use regexps for simple string comparisons. Additionally, the proper way to iterate over a list is `for item in list`. Please read the [Python Tutorial](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/).

Comment: Length of what, exactly?

Comment: @ThiefMaster: I know that RE is too much for a simple substing, but re.search it's more fast than string.find for example becouse it stops at the first occurrence. If you've a lot of strings, I prefer to use an "abnormal" way, but obtain a time less.

Comment: str.find also only searches for one occurence

Comment: Oh yes? thanks :) I'm beginning with python. However I chose "if 'string' in list: #do something"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this case, the output length will be the same as the input length, because you're searching for a specific substring. When you search in `'lost'`, the length of the match will be `2`, because that's what the length of the search parameter is. Now if you want to differentiate between "found" and "not found", remember that `re.search` returns `None` if there is no match. If you really need the length, you can do this:

```
for i in range(len(list)):
    length = 2 if re.search('os', list[i]) else 0
```

I'd recommend using a more typical foreach loop though:

```
for item in list:
    length = 2 if re.search('os', item) else 0
```

And if all you're checking is whether one string appears inside another, well, you can use the `in` operator for that:

```
for item in list:
    length = 2 if 'os' in item else 0
```

Now, if you're looking for a more complex regex, you can retrieve group `0` from the match, which is the entire substring, and check the length of that:

```
for item in list:
    match = re.search('[aeiou]s', item)
    length = len(match.group(0)) if match else 0
```

Comment: Now, I understand what return the length of re.search output...the length of the substring! I was confused and re.search is not what I need.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, assigning a new name to the built-in `list` is a really bad idea. Second, that's not a very Pythonic way to iterate over a list. All Python loops are for-each loops, so simply do:

```
word_list = ['lost','post','cross','help','cost']
for word in word_list:
    match = re.search("os", word)
```

That being said, you are probably looking for the `start` and `end` methods of a match, which tell you exactly where a given match begins in the text being searched, and where it ends.

```
word_list = ['lost','post','cross','help','cost']
for word in word_list:
    match = re.search("os", word)
    if match is not None:
        print match.start(), match.end()
```

Obviously, the difference will be the length. Given your list of words, this will print

```
1 3
1 3
2 4
1 3
```

Answer (score 0):

re.search() returns a match object which has a span method. This method returns two elements, the start position and the end position of the match.